# Исправления ошибки в коде

Tags: python

```
import csv

deparment = {"management department": 122,
              "police department": 77,
              "Department of Education": 33}


deparment["management department"] = 152  # в департаменте управления изменилось количество работников

deparment["police department"] = -15  # в полицейском департаменте уволилось 15 сотрудников

del deparment["Department of Education"]  # департамент образовния был удален

print(f"Всего учеников в депортаменте: {sum(deparment.values())}")  # Выводим на экран общее число сотрудников в департаменте

with open('table_3.csv', 'w') as fl:

    fields = deparment.keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fl)
    # writeheader() - запись названия колонок в файл
    writer.writeheader()

    for d in deparment:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Вот что выводит:

Всего учеников в департаменте: 137
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 18, in 
fields = deparment[0].keys
KeyError: 0

Comment: Текст ошибки указывает на строку, которой в показанном коде нет. Вы где-то нас обманываете

Comment: Возможно, вы забыли сохранить исправленный код в редакторе и запускаете старую версию кода, отличающуюся от той, которую видите в редакторе

Comment: Голосую за -  "департамент образовния был удален"!

Comment: Да  прошу прощения, я исправил ту на которую попросил ответ, но появились новые три...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    writer.writerow(d)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\csv.py", line 147, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
Всего учеников в депортаменте: 137

Comment: попробуйте `for d in department.items()`

Comment: а куда вставить?

Comment: просто последние 2 строки замените на `writer.writerow(deparment)`

Comment: БОЖЕ МОЙ СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ, Я МУЧАЛ ЭТУ ЗАДАЧУ УЖЕ 8 ДЕНЬ СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2):

`csv.DictWriter.writerow` ожидает получить словарь, Вы туда передаёте ключи словаря. Передавайте сам словарь, т.е. замените последние 2 строки на следующий код

```
writer.writerow(deparment)
```